# stuck in the installation

Tags: boot, grub2

i have successfully installed ubuntu on my laptop (no dualboot) but once the prompt, " Please remove the installation medium, then press ENTER:" appears,i removed the medium and hit enter, its just stuck on the logo and doesn't restart automatically. i forced to shutdown my laptop and once i booted up, there is no bootable operating system. i have followed correctly the instructions for the installation.The grub menu is not there,currently my laptop has no OS. I've been repeating the installation many times the results are the same. i checked the boot menu and the ubuntu is missing. im currently using the ubuntu version 18.10

Comment: Have you installed in UEFI mode, likely the one you need, or Bios (Legacy)? Also please [edit] and post the hardware specifications.

Comment: With only Ubuntu, you will not normally get grub menu as only one system to boot which it defaults to. What brand/model system? What video card/chip? If UEFI you have to press escape key after UEFI logo & before grub (or if you would show). If BIOS install, you press & hold shift key from BIOS menu to get grub menu. http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it